# Ask for help, or ask help

Tags: usage

Ask for my help 
Or
Ask my help

Whose help did you ask for?

Or

Whose help did you ask?      In the above two example is the usage of the preposition "for " appropriate or not?

Answer (score 1):

One can "ask a question":

> Can I ask you a question?

One can "ask a" + person:

> Where's the milk? I'll ask an employee.

One can "ask for" + something:

> I asked for some extra ketchup.

One can "ask about" + something:

> My student asked me about their test score.

One can "ask of" + someone:

> I have something to ask of you.

So, "ask for help" is correct, but "ask help" is not (although I have heard native speakers say it).